# Can't login to website (VB.net browser)

Tags: vb.net, authentication, web

I try to login here: http://www.swagbucks.com/p/login

I've tried the following methods:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If element.Id = "sbxJxRegEmail" Then
            Dim i = 0
            Dim strLine = TextBox2.Text
            element.OuterText = strLine
        End If
        If element.Id = "sbxJxRegPswd" Then
            Dim i = 0
            Dim strLine = TextBox3.Text
            element.OuterText = strLine
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and then I tried this

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sbxJxRegEmail").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sbxJxRegPswd").SetAttribute("value", TextBox3.Text)
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginBtn").Focus()
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginBtn").InvokeMember("click")
```

What happens is that the text is entered, but on the browser, it's not really there. It's hard to explain, but basically the username and password are just floating on top of the text boxes like some sort of ghost text and when I then click it, it disappears.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that they are masked inputs, probably need to set the inner text of those fields like so...

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.All("Username").SetAttribute("value", "myusername")
 WebBrowser1.Document.All("Password").SetAttribute("value", "mypassword")

 Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = (WebBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("Password"))
  For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
 element.InnerText = "mypassword"
  Next
```

'You may have to do the same for your username/email

Comment: @user3826567 if this helped, please check as solved and vote, thank you!